# Netty UDP, the reference count of a message is already 0 when I received it

Tags: netty

As the title said,the received message is an io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket instance and the reference count of the 
message is 0 when it was received.I can't retain() it and can't release() it neither.I don't know why and how can I deal with this problem?
My handler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter,as follows:

```
public class ActorMessageHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActorMessageHandler.class);

private ActorRef messageHandlerActor;

public ActorMessageHandler(ActorRef handler) {
    this.messageHandlerActor = handler;
}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    logger.info("actor message handler connected-{}", messageHandlerActor);
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    logger.info("disconnected...");
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    logger.debug("get message {}", msg);
    if (msg instanceof TransportMsg) {
        messageHandlerActor.tell(msg, ActorRef.noSender());
        return;
    }
    if (msg instanceof DatagramPacket) {
        //DatagramPacket recv = ((DatagramPacket) msg).retain();
        DatagramPacket recv = (DatagramPacket) msg;
        logger.info("recv refCnt: {}, {}", recv.content().refCnt(), recv.refCnt());
        DatagramPacket rsp = new DatagramPacket(recv.content().retain(), recv.sender(), recv.recipient());
        messageHandlerActor.tell(msg, ActorRef.noSender());
        if (rsp.refCnt() <= 0) {
            rsp.retain();
        }
        ctx.writeAndFlush(rsp);
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    logger.error("Connection error: " + cause.getMessage());
    cause.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

I logged the refCnt when I received the DatagramPacket and it came out 0 in the method channelRead().If I retain() or release(),IllegalReferenceCountException will be triggered.

```
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, increment: 1
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.retain(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:63)
at io.netty.buffer.WrappedByteBuf.retain(WrappedByteBuf.java:799)
at com.boer.handler.ActorMessageHandler.channelRead(ActorMessageHandler.java:44)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:92)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `MessageToMessageDecoder` earlier in your pipeline, and as the documentation states, you must call `retain()` in the `decode()` method if you pass through the message without actually decoding it (or reuse some parts of the buffer).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I do have a MessageToMessageDecoder in my code.I will try your method.Thank you again.

Comment: It is not directly related to your question, but to me it looks bit dangerous to send off the DatagramPacket to an "external" actor. It introduces quite a lot of maintenance troubles w.r.t managing the lifecycle of the buffers.